# calling Overloaded method from a generic method

Tags: java, generics

How to create a generic method which can call overloaded methods?
I tried but it gives a compilation error.

Test.java:19: incompatible types
found   : java.lang.Object
required: T
T newt = getCloneOf(t);
                                                   ^

```
import java.util.*;

public class Test {


 private Object getCloneOf(Object s) {
  return new Object();
 }

 private String getCloneOf(String s) {
  return new String(s);
 }

 private <T> Set<T> getCloneOf(Set<T> set){
  Set<T> newSet = null;
  if( null != set) {
   newSet = new HashSet<T>();
   for (T t : set) {
    T newt = getCloneOf(t);
    newSet.add(newt);
   }
  }
 }

}
```

Comment: Erm, are you expecting to have a `getCloneOf` method for every possible type?? I mean, if `T` was `Integer`, what are you expecting to happen?

Comment: @asela38 I'm looking to see if there's a way to clone a parameterized type, but the problem is `Object.clone()` is protected unless a class implements `ICloneable`, and `new T()` doesn't work either. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generics_in_Java#Type_erasure Hmmm...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `T` variable can only be set equal to an object of class `T`, or one of it's subclasses. In your case, `getCloneOf()` is returning an `Object`, which isn't going to be a subclass of `T`, or even necessarily what `T` is.

For example:

```
class Parent {
    public void doStuff(){
    }
}

class Child extends Parent {
    public void doDifferentStuff(){
    }
}
```

This is okay:

```
Parent p = new Child();
```

Because this will work even if p is a Child class object, because it inherited that function from Parent:

```
p.doStuff();
```

This is not okay:

```
Child c = new Parent();
```

Because this should theoretically work because the variable is of type Child, but were the previous line allowed this would blow up because a Parent object doesn't have a function with that name.

```
c.doDifferentStuff();
```